# Why may a class trying to change a value in a friendly class's field be triggernig an error?

Tags: c++, class, methods, friend

So I've been learning how friendly classes work, and I created two classes, both being friendly to one another. Howewer, as soon as I write a method to modify a value in another class's field, I get a compilator error, and Visual Studio refuses to elaborate on how to fix it. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
class Human;
class Apple;


class Human
{
public:
    Human();
    Human(int bitepower, string& name); 
    void BiteApple(Apple& other)
     {
        other.weight -= this->bitepower;
    }
    
    void Print()
    {
        cout << "Имя = " << this->name << " Сила укуса = " << this->bitepower << " id = " << this->id << endl;
    }
    ~Human();
private:
    friend Apple;
    int bitepower;
    string name;
    int id;
    static int num;
};
Human::Human()
{
    bitepower = 0;
    num++;
    id = num;
    name = string("Unidentified " + id);
}
Human::Human(int test, string& name)
{
    this->bitepower = test;
    num++;
    id = num;
    this->name = name;
}
int Human::num = 0;
Human::~Human()
{
}


class Apple
{
public:
    Apple();
    Apple(int weight);
    void Print()
    {
        cout << "Apple id = " << this->id << " Weight = " << this->weight << endl;
    }
    ~Apple();

private:
    friend Human;
    int weight;
    static int num;
    int id;
};

Apple::Apple()
{
    weight = 0;
    num++;
    id = num;
}
Apple::Apple(int weight)
{
    this->weight = weight;
    num++;
    id = num;
}
int Apple::num = 0;
Apple::~Apple()
{
}

int main()
{
    //Apple apple1(80);
    //Human egor(20, "Егор");
    //egor.Print();
    //apple1.Print();
    //egor.BiteApple(apple1);
    //egor.Print();
    //apple1.Print();

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the exact method that causes everything to stop working:

```
void BiteApple(Apple& other)
     {
        other.weight -= this->bitepower;
    }
```

After I've localised the problem, I've tried moving the announcements of the classes around, and outlining the very function to be friendly, but to no effect. I just can't seem to find the answer nowhere.

Here is the exact error I get:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvLZx.png)

This reads as: Compilation error occured. Continue and load the last succsessfully built version?

I have also tried moving the declaration of Apple class below the declaration of Human class as suggested, but it had no effect. I  would be grateful to be advised if this can be solved without creating a header file as I have not learned this yet, and if not, I'll need to learn file structure and return to friendly classes later.

Comment: _"...I get a compilator error..."_ what error?  Please include the full error in the question as formatted text.  Please read [ask] with a [mcve].

Comment: "that causes everything to stop working:" what does that mean? The earth stops moving around the sun? Or a compiler error?

Comment: you have a forward declaration of `Apple`, and `Human` can only use pointers to `Apple` it cannot do anything that would need the definition of `Apple`. "Everything"  will work again if you properly use headers and source files (or just move the definition of that one method below the definition of `Apple`)

Comment: Tried swithing the declaration of classes places, also clarified the error I'm getting.

Comment: "Compilation error occured" is not the error. It's just a message saying that there is an error somewhere. So you need to find that actual error. Look for a window or tab labeled Error List or alternatively one called Output.

Comment: Ok, turns out the problem lied in my misunderstanding of Visual Studio interface, I figuerd it out, big thanks to you all